# pandas groupby on a single column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tam','John','Tom','Mark','Tim'],'Surname':['Jones','James','James','Perez','Desouza']})
```

I want to group only based on the 'Name' column. Something like:

```
op=df.groupby(['Name'])
op
```

however, when I try to view the output , I get a message saying: pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy at 0x instead of the output. can someone help ?

Ed

Comment: the `groupby` is an object that is waiting to be instructed what to do with the grouping you've just defined.  Usually, we will aggregate or transform the data within the groups.  See this -> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Comment: If you want to get a sense of what your `groupby` object is you could do something like `for index, df in op: print(index, df)` and that will show you the groups and grouped dataframes it's made up of.